# Laravel polymorphic relation load model by morph name and foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I am trying to create a comment to a commentable model (which is created by using polymorphic relations.) using the morphname key.

For example; i would like create a comment giving the morph name (blog) and foreign_key (1). But the morph name could change. So we don't know which key can be with the request. I don't want to create actions for each resource.

AppServiceProvider:

```
Relation::morphMap([
    'blog' => \App\Models\Blog\BlogPost::class,
    'product' => \App\Models\Commerce\Product::class,
]);
```

Conroller -> action:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'commentable_model' => 'required|string',
    'commentable_id' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    'comment' => 'required|string'
]);

// i am trying to load data using morph name and foreign key here; but it's not working.
$model = $request->commentable_model::findOrFail($request->commentable_id);

$comment = new Comment;
$comment->comment = $request->comment;
$comment->commentable()->associate($model);
$comment->user()->associate(auth('api')->user());
$comment->save();
```

Commentable relation:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->text('comment');
    $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->morphs('commentable');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Data:

> commentable_model => 'blog',
>   commentable_id => 1

I will send these data via api endpoints. So, i would like to use just morhpnames, not full class names.

I could not get it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is it not working? Please add the `commentable` relationship.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Updated.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What's the result of `dd($comment->getAttributes())` at the end?

Comment: Actually i mentioned it above: `$model = $request->commentable_model::findOrFail($request->commentable_id);` this line. The idea is; use findOrFail method on given 'blog' (or any morph name) model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and it was in front of my eyes all the time actually...

We are making the mapping using the Relation class.

I have checked if can we access the relations with any method or variables and the answer is yes.

The short answer is;

```
Relation::$morphMap
```

returns all the mapping as an array.

And my solution for the question is;

```
$model = Relation::$morphMap[$request->commentable_model]::findOrFail($request->commentable_id);
```

Accessing that array value using our given morph name (which is blog).